# Abstract Algebra - Dummit Exercise 3.1.1

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

[image]

This question in Abstract Algebra by Dummit seemed ill-posed to me:

Let $\varphi: G \rightarrow H$ be a homomorphism and let $E$ be a subgroup of $H .$ Provethat $\varphi^{-1}(E) \leq G$ (i.e., the preimage or pullback of a subgroup under a homomorphism is a subgroup). If $E \trianglelefteq H$ prove that $\varphi^{-1}(E) \trianglelefteq G .$ Deduce that ker $\varphi \trianglelefteq G$

In this problem, how do we know $\phi^{-1}(E)$ is well defined? I.e., how do we know there is no $e \in E, \; s.t. \; \phi(g)\neq e \;\; \forall g \in G$? Homomorphisms don't have to be surjective, so I'm thinking $E$ could inherit such and element from $H$.

Edit: Here is my attempted proof:

First we prove some things about $\phi^{-1}$. Let $\phi(x),\phi(y) \in E$:

\begin{align*}
    \phi^{-1}(\phi(x)\phi(y))= \phi^{-1}(\phi(xy)) = xy = \phi^{-1}(\phi(x))\phi^{-1}\phi((y)) 
\end{align*}

Thus $\phi^{-1}$ is also a homomorphism. Also:

\begin{align*}
    \phi^{-1}(x)^{-1} &= \phi^{-1}(1_G)\phi^{-1}(x)^{-1}\\
    &= \phi^{-1}(x^{-1}x)\phi^{-1}(x)^{-1} \\ 
    &= \phi^{-1}(x^{-1}) \phi^{-1}(x) \phi^{-1}(x)^{-1}\\
    &= \phi^{-1}(x^{-1})
\end{align*}

Armed with this knowledge, let $e, e' \in E$, $\phi^{-1}(e),\phi^{-1}(e') \in \phi^{-1}(E)$:

\begin{align*}
    \phi^{-1}(e)\phi^{-1}(e')^{-1} &= \phi^{-1}(e(e')^{-1})\\ &
    = \phi^{-1}(e^{*}) \in \phi^{-1}(E) 
\end{align*}

Thus $\phi^{-1}(E) \leq G$ .

If $E \trianglelefteq H$, then we know $N_H(E) = H, \; hEh^{-1} \forall h \in H$. Let $e \in E$, $\phi^{-1}(e)\in \phi^{-1}(E)$:

\begin{align*}
    g\phi^{-1}(e)g^{-1} &= \phi^{-1}(h)\phi^{-1}(e)\phi(h)^{-1}\\
    &= \phi^{-1}(h e h^{-1})\\
    &= \phi^{-1}(e^*) \in \phi^{-1}(E) 
\end{align*}

Since ${1} \trianglelefteq H$, and $\phi^{-1}(1) = \ker \phi$, $\ker\phi \trianglelefteq G$.

Is this correct?

Comment: Please do [not use pictures for critical portions](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20529/290189) of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not viewable to some, such as those who use screen readers. [Scanned pages from books are discouraged on SE network](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/155600/259305). Questions should contain sufficient context so that it is [answerable with the text alone](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1807/290189).

Comment: So, for any function $f:A\rightarrow B$ where $A$ and $B$ are any sets, if $X\subseteq B$ we define $f^{-1}(X)$ to be $\{a\in A:f(a)\in X\}$... in particular, there is no need for any element of $X$ to actually be in the image of $f$. I agree it's not great notation; one alternative that's perhaps a bit better is $f^{-1}[X]$

Comment: I see, so it is ill-posed... Also, could you explain the second notation? I've never encountered it so I don't know what it means or how to even look it up.

Comment: No, it's not ill-posed. In his last sentence @AtticusStonestrom is just saying that he doesn't like the notation particularly well.

Comment: I see, my proof might have holes in it then. I'll edit it into the question for reference.

Comment: as @CPütz says the question is *not* ill-posed, it just has a (completely standard) clash of notation. I've added a long answer below that hopefully clarifies your confusion

Answer (score 2):

Given a set $A$, let $\mathcal{P}(A)$ denote the "power set" of $A$, which is the set of all subsets of $A$. So, $X\in\mathcal{P}(A)$ if and only if $X\subseteq A$. In particular, note that $\emptyset\in \mathcal{P}(A)$ and $A\in\mathcal{P}(A)$. There is also a canonical injection from $A$ to $\mathcal{P}(A)$ given by $a\mapsto\{a\}$ for any $a\in A$.

Power sets are one way of thinking about the notation you are confused by, based on the following: a function $f:A\rightarrow B$ between sets $A,B$ induces two maps $f^\to:\mathcal{P}(A)\rightleftarrows\mathcal{P}(B):f^\gets$. Can you think about what the action of these maps $f^\to$ and $f^\gets$ might be?

> For $X\in\mathcal{P}(A)$ – ie for $X\subseteq A$ – we define $f^\to(X)=\{f(x):x\in X\}$. Since the range of $f$ is $B$, we have $f^\to(X)\subseteq B$ and thus $f^\to(X)\in\mathcal{P}(B)$ as desired.
>  
>  Conversely, for $Y\in\mathcal{P}(B)$ – ie for $Y\subseteq B$ – we define $f^\gets(Y)=\{a\in A:f(a)\in Y\}$. Clearly this a subset of $A$, and so $f^\gets(Y)\in\mathcal{P}(A)$ as desired. Note that there can be elements in $Y$ that are not in the image of $f$! Indeed, even if every element of $Y$ is outside the image of $f$, this construction is still just fine, and we just get $f^\gets(Y)=\emptyset\in\mathcal{P}(A)$. So $f$ absolutely does not need to be surjective for this construction to work.

These induced functions will always exists, without any conditions required on $f$. Now, the issue for you in this question is that it is common practice in mathematics to abuse notation slightly and refer to what we are calling $f^\to$ and $f^\gets$ as $f$ and $f^{-1}$, respectively. So, in particular, given a subset $X\subseteq A$ we denote $f(X)=\{f(x):x\in X\}\subseteq B$, and given a subset $Y\subseteq B$ we denote $f^{-1}(Y)=\{a\in A:f(a)\in Y\}\subseteq A$.

These maps do *not* act on $A$ and $B$, but on $\mathcal{P}(A)$ and $\mathcal{P}(B)$. It is unfortunate notation, for a number of reasons. For instance – and this is the source of your confusion – $f^\gets$ exists even if $f$ is not invertible. So the fact that $f^\gets$ exists says nothing about whether $f$ is invertible (or even surjective) or not. However, this abuse of notation is completely standard in much of mathematics, so you'll have to get comfortable with it.

(Another alternative to the clash of notation is as follows. For a subset $X\subseteq A$, we define $f[X]=f^\to(X)$ and, for a subset $Y\subseteq B$, we define $f^{-1}[Y]=f^\gets(Y)$. Using these square brackets when we are referring to subsets mitigates the clash of notation in question. This convention is fairly common, so you might want to adopt it for future use.)

Finally we can return to your question. What D&F call $\varphi^{-1}(E)$ is just the set $\varphi^\gets(E)=\{g\in G:\varphi(g)\in E\}$. There absolutely may be elements of $E$ not in the image of $\varphi$; this doesn't change anything. As an illustrative example, using this notation we have that $\ker(\varphi)=\varphi^{-1}(\{1\})$, where $1$ denotes the identity element of $H$; does this make sense?

So, armed with this correct definition in mind, do you think you can now solve the problem? (Note that your current proposed solution is incorrect, because it *is* assuming that $\varphi$ is bijective onto $E$. What D&F are calling $\varphi^{-1}$ is really $\varphi^\gets$; it acts on *subsets* of $H$ and is guaranteed to exist. On the other hand, what you denote by $\varphi^{-1}$ in your post acts on *elements* of $H$, and is not guaranteed to exist by any means.)

This might seem like a long-winded digression, but this is a very common convention in mathematics, and you may as well start getting used to it now!

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. I still have to read it over more than once to absorb it properly, but I do see where I'm mistaken in my proof. Essentially I assumed that for all $e \in E$, $\phi^{-1}(e)$ is defined, which is incorrect; I should really look at the set $\phi^{-1}(E)$. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @OhMuzGawd great, so glad it helped! let me know if you have any questions :)

Comment: I like $f^\to$ and $f^\gets$ for the induced functions on subsets; easy to write and functorial.

Comment: @egreg oh yeah that's much nicer notation, will edit the post

Answer (score 2):

First and foremost, personally I'd avoid using the symbol "$\varphi^{-1}(E)$", as this misleads to thinking (as seemingly you did) that an inverse map exists, which in general is not the case. For this reason, I'll use in place of that a more neat (to me) "$\varphi^{\leftarrow}(E)$".

So, by definition, $\varphi^\leftarrow(E):=\{g\in G\mid \varphi(g)\in E\}$; since $E$ is a group, $\varphi^\leftarrow(E)\ne\emptyset$ as $e_G\in \varphi^\leftarrow(E)$. Now, let $g,g'\in \varphi^\leftarrow(E)$; then $\varphi(gg')=\varphi(g)\varphi(g')\in E$, because $E$ is a group, and hence  $gg'\in \varphi^\leftarrow(E)$. Likewise, let $g\in \varphi^\leftarrow(E)$; then, $\varphi(g^{-1})=\varphi(g)^{-1}\in E$, again because $E$ is a group; therefore, $g^{-1}\in \varphi^\leftarrow(E)$. By the subgroup criteria (closure and closure by inverses), indeed $\varphi^\leftarrow(E)\le G$.

For the second part, $\forall g \in G$:

\begin{alignat}{1}
g\varphi^\leftarrow(E)g^{-1} &= \{gkg^{-1}\in G\mid \varphi(k)\in E\} \\
&= \{k'\in G\mid \varphi(g^{-1}k'g)\in E\} \\
&= \{k'\in G\mid \varphi(g)^{-1}\varphi(k')\varphi(g)\in E\} \\
&= \{k'\in \varphi^{\leftarrow}(E)\mid \varphi(g)^{-1}\varphi(k')\varphi(g)\in E\}\cup \{k'\in G\setminus\varphi^{\leftarrow}(E)\mid \varphi(g)^{-1}\varphi(k')\varphi(g)\in E\} \\
&\stackrel{(E\unlhd H)}{=} \varphi^{\leftarrow}(E)\cup\emptyset \\
&= \varphi^{\leftarrow}(E)
\end{alignat}

and hence $\varphi^{\leftarrow}(E)\unlhd G$.

For the final corollary, note that $\operatorname{ker}(\varphi)=\varphi^{\leftarrow}(\{e_H\})$ and $\{e_H\}\unlhd H$.